# Logstash create a new field based on existing field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok

I have data coming from database queries using jdbc input plugin and result from queries contains `url` field from which I want to extract a few properties.

Example urls:

> - /incident.do?sys_id=0dc18b246faa17007a64cbe64f3ee4e1&sysparm_view
> - /navpage_form_default.do
> - /u_pm_prov_project_list.do?sysparm_userpref_module=fa547ce26f661
> - JOB: email read events process
> - JOB: System - reduce resources

I added regex patterns in grok patterns file:

```
webpage_category .*
job_type .*
```

I have two types of url so I used if in filter block to distinguish between them

Config I tried so far:

```
filter {
       if [url] =~ /JOB: .*/ {
               grok {
                    patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"]
                    match => {
                             "url" => "JOB: %{job_type:job_type}"
                    }
               }
        } else
        if [url] =~ /\/.*\.do\?.*/ {
                grok {
                     patterns_dir => ["/etc/logstash/patterns"]
                     match => {
                              "url" => "/{webpage_category:webpage_category}\.do\?.*"
                     }
                 }
         }
}
```

Creation of a new field for urls starting with `JOB:` works properly but `webpage_category` is not working at all. Is it because regex can not be used inside of match?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to use `grok` pattern inside a `mutate` filter, which wouldn't work. `mutate` and `grok` are two separate filter plugins.

You need to use `add_field` inside grok filter if you want to use grok pattern to create a field. please remember `add_field` [is supported by all filter plugins.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#plugins-filters-grok-add_field)

Please have a look at following example,

```
filter {
  grok {
    add_field => { "foo_%{somefield}" => "Hello world, from %{host}" }
  }
}
```

In your case, it will be,

```
filter{
   grok {
      add_field => {
         "webpage_category" => "%{webpage_category:url}"
          "job_type" => "%{job_type:url}"
       }
   }
}
```

Please also make sure, `patterns_dir` is imported,

```
patterns_dir => ["./patterns"] => ["./patterns"]
```

please checkout [grok filter documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) as well.

Comment: I modified filter according to your advice but now instead of empty fields they look like that: `webpage_category` - `%{webpage_category:url}` and `job_type` - `%{job_type:url}`. I put my patterns inside of `grok-patterns` file.

Comment: can you simply try printing `%{webpage_category:url}` and `%{job_type:url}` ?

Comment: How can I print it? Nothing shows up in the logstash logs.

Comment: one question, in which field your entire log is stored? `message`?

Comment: would you be able to add the output of kibana or search query please

Comment: Updated status of the problem in the question. Instead of `add_field` I had to use `match` because `add_field` didn't work properly. I still have problems with `webpage_category` and I don't know why. I don't have message field because Logstash maps DB table to final fields, so for this issue `url` field is only needed.